# Is there a clean way to hide model attributes from some users in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to introduce field-level permissions in my app that would effectively hide/nullify model field values from some users, while showing them to others.  A user would need to be able to do something like this:

```
class MyRestrictedModel(HypotheticalMixin, models.Model):
    public = CharField(max_length=128)
    restricted = RestrictedCharField(
        max_length=128,
        permitted_groups=("group1",)
    )

user1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)  # in group1
user2 = User.objects.get(pk=2)  # NOT in group 1

model_instance1 = MyRestrictedModel.objects.get(pk=1).restrict(user1)
model_instance2 = MyRestrictedModel.objects.get(pk=1).restrict(user2)

print(model_instance1.public)  # "this is public data"
print(model_instance1.restricted)  # "this is restricted data"

print(model_instance2.public)  # "this is public data"
print(model_instance2.restricted)  # None
```

I think I might be able to hack something together to get this working, but I'd hate to do that work if something more robust and community-accepted was available, so I thought I'd ask here.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want add attribute, method, groups etc so you know if a user is restricted or not. Assuming you have `user.is_restricted` attribute:

```
class RestrictManager(models.Manager):

  def by_user(self,user):

     queryset = super(RestrictManager,self).get_queryset()
     if user.is_restricted:
       queryset = queryset.annotate(field_to_show=None) # field_to_show is a queryset field (not in any model)
     else:
       queryset = queryset.annotate(field_to_show=secret_field)

     return queryset

class MyRestrictedModel(models.Model):

   field1 = models.CharField...
   restricted_objects = RestrictManager()
```

In your code:

```
q = MyRestrictedModel.restricted_objects.by_user(self.request.user)
# Now use q as usual, q.all(), q.get(...), q.filter(...)
```

You can of course add more method like `by_group` etc, and even set `objects=RestrictManager()` to replace the objects default manager.

Comment: I don't think that this will solve my problem.  I want the manager to return all of the records, I just want some of the *fields* in those records to be `None` instead of their proper values in cases when certain users are looking at them.

Comment: OK, so use annotate. Updated the answer.

Comment: Interesting, can you give me an example of how to use `.annotate()` to override the value of a field?

Comment: From django 1.9 annotate accepts also non aggregates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: but I can't set `.annotate(restricted="something")`.  It complains that `The annotation 'restricted' conflicts with a field on the model.`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use a django package that deals specifically with detailed permissions. See [here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/) all this kind of packages. The right for you - which has field level permissions management - is [`django-permissions`](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission). But there are others too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already hit up django-packages and dug into django-permissions, django-rules, and django-role-permissions.  Those are the only packages that claim to support field-level permissions on Django Packages.  The thing is, *none of them do*.  Two of the three are poorly documented means of object permissions, and django-rules is a very robust means of object-level permissions that doesn't even use the word "field" anywhere.... that's why I'm here :-(